# Clear DateField in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, user-interface, date, flex3

there's no way to clear a date after it has been inserted! I had to add an ugly button near it to clear it programmatically...

Do you have a nicer solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can set editable="true" if you want to allow the text field to be cleared.

You can also CTRL-click the selected date to de-select it, though, it would probably take more to explain that to your users than the "ugly clear button".

Comment: thanks.. if I wanted to delete on double click how can I do that in a general way? I tried doubleclick="this.text=null" but this doesn't refer to the current tag instance. What then?